# $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition on $fg$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, epsilon-delta

Given that $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(a,b)}{f(x,y)} = l_1,\lim_{(x,y)\to(a,b)}{g(x,y)} = l_2$$
we need to prove that $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(a,b)}{f(x,y).g(x,y)} = l_1l_2$$ by the epsilon-delta definition.

Comment: Good.  You *do* need to prove that.  Now get started.  If you have any questions feel free to ask.  But as you don't have any questions yet, go ahead and get started.

Comment: @fleablood (+1)

Comment: Sorry for not elaborating. i tried but couldn't get the expression $|f(x,y)*g(x,y)-l_1*l_2|$ into suitable $\epsilon$

Comment: Did you already do the case for functions of one variable?  Why not try to imitate that proof for two variables?

Comment: i was in a little hurry. sorry all of you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One trick that is useful in cases like this is what I learned to call the "fat 0". The idea is to add and subtract the same value so as to turn it into something useful. In this case, consider:
\begin{align}
|f(x,y)g(x,y) - l_1l_2| &= |f(x, y)g(x, y) - f(x,y)l_2 + f(x,y)l_2 - l_1l_2| \\
&\leq |f(x, y)g(x,y) - f(x, y)l_2| + |f(x,y)l_2 - l_1l_2|
\end{align}
Now, the trick is that each of these summands should be something you can work with a bit better by using the existence of the limits for $f$ and $g$, respectively.

Hopefully this helps!